# Find a minimal spanning set of a set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, span

I'm supposed to find a minimal spanning set of $W = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) | \operatorname{Tr}(A) = 0\}$

First of all, what is a minimal spanning set? I can't find the term anywhere in the notes my teacher has posted.

Is it simply $\operatorname{Span}(W) =  \{ α \cdot\begin{bmatrix} a && a_2 && a_3 &&... && a_n 
\\ b_1 && b && b_3 &&... && b_n
\\ c_1 && c_2 && c &&... && c_n
\\ \vdots && \vdots && \vdots&& \ddots && \vdots
\\ e_1 && e_2 && e_3 &&... && e
\end{bmatrix} | α \in \mathbb{R},\ a + b +c +... +e= 0\}$
?

Comment: A minimal spanning set is the smallest subset of $W$ that spans $W$.

Comment: What does it mean "find"? You have already found it, it is the set of all matrices with trace zero..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A spanning set in $W$ is a collection of elements in $W$ which spans $W$, i.e. a family $f_1, \dots, f_n \in W$ such that each $x \in W$ can be written as $x = a_1 f_1 + \dots a_n f_n$ for real coefficients $a_i$.

The spanning set is minimal if you can't find a spanning family with fewer vectors. The number of vectors in a minimal spanning set of $W$ is the *dimension* of $W$.

The dimension of $W$ in your example is $n^2 - 1$ since $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $n^2$ and $\operatorname{Tr}(A)=0$ is one equation. Therefore, you need to find $n^2 - 1$ linearly independent elements in $W$.

So consider the following matrices:

- the ones which have one entry outside of the diagonal equal to $1$ and $0$ everywhere else  (there are $n(n-1)$ of these);
- the ones which have 1 on the entry $(k, k)$ for $k < n$ and $-1$ for the entry $(n,n)$ and $0$ everywhere else (there are $n - 1$ such matrices).

These are clearly in $W$ and linearly independent. Moreover, it is spanning, because $n(n-1) + n-1 = n^2 - n + n - 1 = n^2 - 1$.

Comment: Could this be generalized for n matrices?

Comment: Yes my argument works for matrices $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. I use
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0& 0\\ 0& 0& -1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1& 0\\ 0& 0& -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ for the second to last matrix. With this one, it's more obvious how to generalise in $n$ dimensions.